# PHP imagemagick set image offset

Tags: php, imagemagick

So I am trying to combine three images like this:

```
$image = new \Imagick();
$image->newImage(240, 180, "#1341BA");
$image->newImage(240, 180, "#D9EBCA");
$image->newImage(240, 180, "#197067");

$image->resetIterator();
$combined = $image->appendImages(true);
```

And now I need to set offset so that created image could look like these images from 1 to 5:

For example I select offset to be `= 1` so the created image should look like the first example and if I select offset to be `= 5` it should look like the last example.

I am completely new to `ImageMagick` so is it possible to do this somehow? Would appreciate some help

Comment: Perhaps use montage equivalent in PHP? or smush equivalent in PHP?  Alternately use PHP exec() to do these commands. Otherwise, you will need to create spacer images and use those with your images.

Comment: See https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.montageimage.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.smushimages.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.borderimage.php